# Wordpress Post that don't link

Tags: wordpress

We have converted a paper newsletter to a WordPress site.  One thing we're struggling with is that all the posts have to link to another page where you read the article.

We have some items that were just a photo and cut-line in the paper version that we'd like to offer on our homepage and we don't want them linking to a "Read More" since the Read More doesn't offer any additional content.

Any ideas on a work around?

Comment: This depends critically on the template you're using on your WP site, and on several other factors. It's not possible to help you without more info.

Comment: What do you want to do ? Make link to full article or opposite ?

Comment: We're using the Memoir theme from ElegantThemes.com

We want to remove the Read More button from some posts that offer just a picture and cutline.  The other posts we want treated normally.